# ActiveMQ/ DynamicQueue/advisorytemporary Queue admin access

Tags: activemq-classic

I am configuring the queues in AWS MQ and in configuration file i have added queues with their name and access but few queues are creating dynamic or advisory queue and due to this the access provided to that queue is not working and when i am giving admin access to those queues are working fine.

I just want to understand why admin access is working for dynamic and advisory queues and why its not working with consumer and producer user access.

Also for the detail my actual queue name is test1 but when it is creating the connection it is expecting dynamic/queue1, when i was trying to connect with consumer/producer credentials it is not working and giving the error No such queue found test1, but when i am trying to access through admin it is working successfully, could you help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ "Classic" (used by Amazon MQ) requires `admin` authorization in order to automatically create a destination on the user's behalf. The `read` and `write` authorizations only allow a user to consume and produce messages to a destination respectively.

You can find additional details in the [ActiveMQ "Classic" documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/security.html).

Comment: thank you for your response, you mean without admin access i can't access dynamic queues?

Comment: Also for the detail my actual queue name is test1 but when it is creating the connection it is expecting dynamic/queue1, when i was trying to connect with consumer/producer credentials it is not working and giving the error No queue found test1, but when i am trying to access through admin it is working successfully, could you help me on this

Comment: Could you please help me in the above query- #activemq #dynamicqueue #advisoryQueue

Comment: You can *access* (i.e. read from and write to) a dynamically created queue without the `admin` authorization, but the dynamically created queue can't be *created* without the `admin` authorization.

Comment: Regarding your other concern, please create a new question and explain your full use-case. Thanks!